# Проверка аргументов в конструкторе или в свойствах

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть класс который описывает человека и содержит публичный свойства ФИО.

Каждое свойство связано с приватным полем.

В свойствах реализована проверка корректности значений. Если что-то не так, то падаю.

Имеется так же конструктор, который так же может принять ФИО на вход.

Собственно вопрос:

Правильно ли в конструкторе выполнять присвоение прямо через свойства или правильнее будет сделать доп. проверку минуя свойства и привязать все прямо к приватным полям?

Comment: Свойства для того и нужны, чтобы инкапсулировать работу с полем.

Comment: @Grundy, ну т.е правильнее в конструкторе отдать проверку на свойства? А если я работаюв  доверительной зоне (внутри приватных методов, где косяков нету), то работать напрямую с полями(Вроде, скорость выше)?

Comment: Если тебе нужны проверки, которые уже реализованы, обычно не следует их дублировать несколько раз для каждого отдельного случая

Comment: Если у вас есть поле и свойство, которое устанавливает поле, и вы хотите избежать лапши в коде, то используйте поле только внутри свойства и больше нигде.

Answer (score 2):

Где делать правильно зависит от многих факторов, например, требований по производительности (работа через свойства будет медленнее, чем напрямую), от стратегии обработки ошибок (возможно у вас будут разные требования по ошибкам генерируемым в свойствах и в конструкторе, как в примере ниже), т.е. надо смотреть каждый раз с нуля. В большинстве случаев, наиболее оптимальный вариант, когда у вас все проверки в свойстве, а в конструкторе (как и в остальных методах) вы работаете через свойства. Теперь к примеру. Допустим, мы хотим при присвоении свойству кидать информацию с именем свойства, а в конструкторе с именем параметра. В этом случае у нас будет вот такой вот код:

```
class Person
{
    private string _lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lastName)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                {
                    _lastName = value;
                }
                else if (value == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(LastName)} не может быть null", nameof(LastName));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(LastName)} не может быть пустой или содержать только пробелы", nameof(LastName));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Person(string lastName)
    {
        try
        {
            LastName = LastName;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(lastName)} не может быть null", nameof(lastName));
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(lastName)} не может быть пустой или содержать только пробелы", nameof(lastName));
        }
    }
}
```

Видите как благая идея упирается в общую рекомендацию. И тут надо или поменять требования, чтобы отказаться от требования о различных названиях (что существенно повысит читаемость и сопровождаемость кода, но усложнит отладку) или вынести присвоение в отдельный метод в который передавать имя того элемента, который должен фигурировать в сообщении об ошибке (опять же, если это возможно сделать в соответствии с вашими требованиями, у меня в примере, не меняется тип Exception, а у вас он может меняться). Вот более хороший код:

```
class Person
{
    private string _lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            SetLastName(value);
        }
    }

    private void SetLastName(string lastName, [CallerMemberName]string elementName = "")
    {
        if (lastName != _lastName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            {
                _lastName = lastName;
            }
            else if (lastName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{elementName} не может быть null", elementName);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{elementName} не может быть пустой или содержать только пробелы", elementName);
            }
        }
    }

    public Person(string lastName)
    {
        SetLastName(lastName, nameof(lastName));
    }
}
```

Выводы:

1. Универсальных рекомендаций нет. Каждый раз надо включать голову.
2. Если лень включать голову, то из конструктора и всех остальных мест обращаться к свойствам.